# Can you make the Direction of Gravity dependend on the Rotation of an Object?

Tags: physics

Ok so here is the Visual Example of what i mean:

[image]

The arrows show in which direction Gravity is pulling. So, is there anyway to do something like this ? Maybe that Gravity is depended on the Normal Vector of a selected Surface ? Or i guess the Invers Normal Vector so it points in the right direction since the N Vector points upwards.

AS far as i understand it, in Blender Gravity is a Global Constant and not local. Which means you cant do that. But can you ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: _This answer_ has a trick which basically involves setting global gravity to 0 and then defining local attraction with a bit of python. Link is here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18106/75504

Comment: Hm i looked at the Post and the script dosnt seem to do anything on my end...

Comment: Could you please clarify. Do you wish to set scene gravity based on one face normal, If so I think (theoretically you can) via a driver or handler.

Comment: Ok so in an Ideal world, i would want this: Gravity depends on the Face Normal BUT it only has any effect in the Face Area. So looking at this: https://i.imgur.com/pSsx2BL.png 
The 4 Verts of each Face create a "Tube" or Corridor in which Gravity is depended on the Vector. Everything outsidde of this Corridor has no Gravitational attraction at all. So the Faces cast a corridor in which gravity is depended on the Vector.